# Why can't python find this module that I've installed django-lockdown?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a Django app that is failing because it cannot find a module that I've installed. It's called Django-Lockdown. Can someone show me how to fix this issue?

Step 1: Start the virtualEnv and make sure that the module is installed:

```
$ source /opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/bin/activate


(myApp)$ pip -r requirements.txt
<SNIPPED>

(myApp)$ pip show django-lockdown
---
Name: django-lockdown
Version: 1.0
Location: /opt/virtualEnvs/jobBidSite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_lockdown-1.0-py2.7.egg
Requires:
```

Step #2: Run the python shell and manually import this module. It works.

```
(myApp)$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lockdown
>>> exit()
```

Step #3: Start the debelopment server. It fails because it says it cannot find this module. Why?

```
(myApp)$ sudo python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named lockdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/opt/virtualEnvs/jobBidSite/lib/python2.7/site-packages` the module is in your virtualenv python packages, you are using the system python `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` for django.

Don't use `sudo`, it is running the system python.

Comment: I don't understand. This is running in a virtualenv. So it shouldn't be installed to the System python location, right?

Comment: it is installed in your virtualenv but django is running from your system python.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes. Stupid me! When I did Sudo, of course it was no longer in the VirtualEnv.

Comment: No worries, we all have those moments ;)